# How can I send direct input to games, specifically Roblox, using Python?

Tags: python, roblox

I've been trying to use Python to send inputs to Roblox, but to no avail. What I know so far is that Roblox requires DirectInput, as most games do.

I've seen people successfully send keystrokes, but haven't seen any example of mouse movements or mouse clicks; to complete my goal, I need to be able to move the mouse, send clicks, as well as keyboard inputs, to an active Roblox window.

I'm currently using Python 3.9, if that's of any help.

Answer (score 0):

i believe [PyDirectinput](https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/) works to click Roblox

```
import pydirectinput

pydirectinput.click()
```